# Any recommendation for newer graphic card for 3D modelling and rendering

Tags: nvidia

For >3 years I have a computer with  ASUS PRIME Z390-A, I7-9700K, 32Gb memory, 650W PSU and ASUS TUF-GTX1660S-O6G-GAMING. Any recommendation for newer graphic card for 3D modelling and rendering (Rhino, keyshot, blender) that is not to expensive, fit the motherboard limitations and will boost the computer?

Comment: Budget?  $200,$300?  The recommended PSU for your GPU is 450w, so your power supply isn't going to be enough for a significant upgrade.  However, your video card is pci-e x16 so ANY modern card will fit, and backward compatibility will drop the pci-e speed to match your motherboard.